# Casting a section of a std::vector<char> to std::array<char, n>, c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the following code violate strict aliasing or otherwise result in undefined behaviour according to the C++11 standard? Are there better ways to achieve the same functionality?

```
void do_things(const std::array<char, 64> &block) {
   // ...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> buffer(64);
    do_things(reinterpret_cast<const std::array<char, 64> &>(buffer[0]));
}
```

### tldr: Using `const char *` is a lot less painful

edit: since `sizeof(std::array<char, n>)` isn't guaranteed to be equal to `n`, I then propose the following:

```
void do_things(const char (&block)[64]) {
   // ...
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> buffer(64);
    do_things(reinterpret_cast<char (&)[64]>(buffer[0]));
}
```

According my understanding of aliasing this should not result in undefined behaviour and capture the semantics of passing an array of fixed size. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Related: Is there some reason you don't just write an iterator-based general solution instead?

Comment: Of course this breaks strict aliasing. Moreover, `std::array` isn't even guaranteed to have no additional data members other than the elements...

Comment: @WhozCraig I need to guarantee that the memory is contiguous (although I suppose with random-access iterators it would be fine)

Comment: @T.C. I was under the impression that std::array was supposed to be POD and drop in replacement for C arrays - i.e. you could do things like union { std::array<char, 4> bytes, unsigned i };

Comment: @HerpDerpington Fyi, random access iterators don't guarantee contiguous storage. [`std::deque<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) provides such iterators, for example, with no such contiguous storage guarantee. If you could live with random access iterators, however, an SFINAE enablement strategy on an iterator-based solution may be sufficient. Just food for thought.

Comment: @HerpDerpington It must be an aggregate and you must be able to initialize it with `array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };` if the initializer_list is up to `N` comma-separated `T`s. But there's no rule that says the implementation can't put in something extra.

Comment: `std::vector<>` guarantees contiguous memory if that's all you need.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think this may be just one of the cases where I'm overthinking it, A const char * is perfectly fine here.

Comment: I take back the first sentence of my first comment. This doesn't break the strict aliasing rule due to the 4th bullet point [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing), which is the 6th bullet point in §3.10 [basic.lval]/p10. But you pretty much can't do anything whatsoever with the resulting reference to `std::array`, because "If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior is undefined." (§9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p2)

Comment: @HerpDerpington I can't think of a rule that your new version breaks. I'm also not sure why you would ever need to do something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strict aliasing rule refers to §3.10 [basic.lval]/p10, which provides that

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>     contained union)
> - [...]

Thus, accessing an object of type `char` through a glvalue of type `std::array<char, N>` does not break this rule, because `std::array<char, N>` is an aggregate type that includes `char` as an element of a nonstatic subaggregate data member.

However, you still can't do anything useful with the resulting reference without invoking undefined behavior because of a different rule - §9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p2:

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object
>   that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior
>   is undefined.

It's also worth noting that no rule in the standard guarantees that `sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N`. The only things the standard guarantees is that `std::array<T, N>` is an aggregate type and it can be initialized using a *braced-init-list* containing up to `N` `T`s. The implementation is free to add extra stuff.

Depending on what `do_things` needs, you may want to make your function take random access iterators, or simply a pointer. Alternatively, if you want to limit your function to take only `std::vector` and `std::array`s, you can write overloads that take const refs to those and call a helper function taking `const char *` that does the actual work.

---

The new version doesn't break any rule I can think of, but it's fairly bad design to require `reinterpret_cast` to be used pretty much every time your function is called. If you accidentally declared `buffer` as a `std::vector<std::string>`, or wrote `buffer` instead of `buffer[0]`, the compiler will happily compile your code without a warning, with potentially disastrous results.

Comment: §9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static]/p2 violation occurs because indexing a std::array is calls operator[] right?

Comment: @HerpDerpington Correct.